# Passing Context From one view to another view

Tags: django

I have two views one that accepts inputs and the other for confirmation and execution of an action. My problem is that the context data from the first view seems inaccessible in the confirmation view.

Here is the input view. PreprocessinputationView:

```
def PreprocessInputationView(request, **kwargs):
    proj_pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    project = Project.objects.get(id=proj_pk)  
    df      = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)
    n_cols  = df.keys

    context            = {}
    context['df']      = df
    context['n_cols']  = n_cols
    context['project'] = project

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # try:       
        checked_value   = request.POST.getlist(u'predictors')
        method = ''.join(request.POST.getlist(u'method'))
        if checked_value and method:
            context['checked_value'] = checked_value
            context['method'] = method

            return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/confirm_inputation.html', context)

    return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/preprocess_inputation.html', context)
```

The confirmation view goes here. ConfirmInputationView:

```
def ConfirmInputationView(request, context):
    print('method:', context['method'])
    project = context['project']  
    df      = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)
    n_cols  = df.keys

    filename = project.base_file.name
    tmp = filename.split('/')
    filename = str(tmp[1:])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # try:       
        checked_value = context['checked_value']
        method        = context['method']

        if checked_value and (method=='mean'):
            df[checked_value].fillna(df[checked_value].mean())

            # df.drop(columns=checked_values, inplace=True)
            new_df            = df.to_csv(index=False)

            updated_file      = ContentFile(new_df)
            updated_file.name = filename 

            project.base_file = updated_file
            project.save()

            str_checked_value = ', '.join(checked_value)
            context['str_checked_value'] = str_checked_value
            if str_checked_value:       
                messages.success(request, f'Inputation to column(s) {str_checked_value} successful!')         

    return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/preprocess_inputation.html', context)
```

The confirmation template. Confirm_inputation.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_heading %}
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Delete Project</h1>
</div>
{% endblock page_heading %}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron col-xl-8 col-md-6 mb-1"">
    <form method=" POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class='form-group'>
            <p>

                You have chosen <strong>{{ method }}</strong> as an inputation method?

                Are you sure you want to proceed?
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger float-sm-right mr-1" type="submit">Yes, Delete</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary float-sm-right mr-1" href="{% url 'project-detail' project.id %}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When the imputation is confirmed the program should be able to execute this code `df[checked_value].fillna(df[checked_value].mean())` which is inside the `if request.method == 'POST':`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering the confirmation template in `PreprocessInputationView` view you should return the view function. That is, replace

`return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/confirm_inputation.html', context)`

With

`return ConfirmInputationView(request, context)`

Comment: Following your suggestion yields an error ```No columns to parse from file```.

Comment: Can you tell me from which line that error rises from? Or give me the entire stack trace.

Comment: I already solved the error. My intention for the ```confirmImputationView``` and the ```confirm_imputation.html``` is to confirm the imputation made by the user in the ```preprocessImputationView```. With your suggestion the ```confirm_imputation.html``` template will no longer be displayed for the application to confirm any user action. Please help me on this... Thank you!